# Using gdal in canopy, hdf file is not supported

Tags: python, gdal, canopy

I want to recreate this code in Canopy:

https://jgomezdans.github.io/gdal_notes/ipython.html

But if I do exactly the same I get the error:

```
ERROR 4: `\Users\Lisa\Documents\Data1.hdf'
```

So I tried to import a couple of libraries that can help me, but I still get the same error.

```
from osgeo import gdal
#import numpy as np?
# import pyhdf?
#import pandas as pd?

#import hdf5
g = gdal.Open("\Users\Lisa\Documents\Data1.hdf")
```

So I tried a few combinations with the different libraries, but it still doesn't work.

(NOTE: `import hdf5` hasn't work yet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43466901/package-manager-canopy-error-import-hdf5)

Has anybody an idea which library is necessary or why my code isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your path string contains unescaped backslashes by accident. Python interprets these as [escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

Try doing `g = gdal.Open(r"\Users\Lisa\Documents\Data1.hdf")`. Note the `r`-prefix in front of the string literal which marks the string as "raw" and keeps the backslashes as is.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install gdal?

If you install gdal using the package manager, it will be installed with the appropriate dependencies.

The gdal package installed with Canopy supports the following drivers:

```
~/Desktop $ gdal-config --formats
gxf gtiff hfa aigrid aaigrid ceos ceos2 iso8211 xpm sdts raw dted mem jdem envisat elas fit vrt usgsdem l1b nitf bmp airsar rs2 ilwis rmf leveller sgi srtmhgt idrisi gsg ingr ers jaxapalsar dimap gff cosar pds adrg coasp tsx terragen blx msgn til r northwood saga xyz hf2 kmlsuperoverlay ctg e00grid zmap ngsgeoid iris map cals safe sentinel2 mrf wcs wms plmosaic wmts grib bsb netcdf hdf5 gif jpeg png pcraster pcidsk rik ozi pdf arg
```

`hdf5` is in it. If you file is an hdf5 file, it should work.

I would also recommend using the following code to get more information about the underlying issue:

```
import gdal
gdal.UseExceptions()
```